# Generating report directly from Mysql Query data (using groupby, count)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have two tables for storing images and its related exif data:

`image_table` has records like below:

```
(query: select * from image_table where order_id = 3030303)
```

[image]

`image_exif_info` table has records like below:

```
(query: select * from image_exif_info where 
image_id in (select image_id from image_table where order_id = 3030303)
```

[image]

As marked in the second screenshot, I am interested in the `Make` and `Model` fields.

What I wanted to do is write a query that will show me data like this (REPORT):

```
Make          Model              # of photos
Canon         CanonEOS 400D      (200)
Nikon         Nikon D3200        (120)
....          .....              ....
```

I know that I can write a query and loop through and do count etc to get this report. However I am trying hard to improve my SQL skills, so I am trying to create this report using a single query.

So far I have gotten this far :

```
select distinct i.value,count(i.image_id) from image_exif_info i 
where (i.key ='Make' or i.key = 'Model')
and i.image_id in (select image_id from image where order_id =303030)
group by value
```

The result of the query above is:

```
Canon                 200
CanonEOS 400D         200
Nikon                 120
Nikon D3200           120
```

I would like it to be identical to what I showed above under (REPORT)

Comment: Given that you have access to application level code, I would be tempted to solve the 'display' part of this problem there, rather than with a pivot query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using a table subquery.

```
SELECT exif.Make, exif.Model, COUNT(i.image_id) AS "# of photos"
FROM image_table i
INNER JOIN (SELECT x.image_id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN x.`key`='Make' THEN x.`value` ELSE '' END) AS Make,
       MAX(CASE WHEN x.`key`='Model' THEN x.`value` ELSE '' END) AS Model
      FROM image_exif_info x
      WHERE x.`key` IN ('Make','Model')
      GROUP BY x.image_id) exif
ON i.image_id = exif.image_id
GROUP BY exif.Make, exif.Model;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38dc4/11

The subquery is a pivot that gives each image_id and the make and model.  That is then joined to the image_table by the image_id and grouped by the make and model.

Comment: That, sir, is AWESOME! I wish I could +1 more than once! Thanks a lot!!